# Azure Automation | Cannot grant 'User Access Administrator' role to service principle

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need to grant my Azure Automation service principle permission to behave as a User Access Administrator; to grant RBACs on resources in some scenarios.

I cannot see the permission in the api permission list.

I tried PUT against the REST API which returned:

```
400 : {
  "error": {
    "code": "PrincipalTypeNotSupported",
    "message": "Principals of type Application cannot validly be used in role assignments."
  }
}
```

Is this impossible or can it be achieved? I can see why this might not be desirable for a lot of scenarios due to *permission escalation*. Alternatively, I will have to manually grant permissions when building the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and it works fine for me.

So this issue is probably caused by that a wrong `principalId` is provided.

`principalId` is the object id of the service principle.

You can find it in Azure Portal to verify it. (**All services** > **Automation Accounts** > {your automation account}| Run as accounts > **Azure Run As Account** > **Service Principal Object ID**)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate the powershell cmdlet granting 'User Access Administrator' on Azure Active Directory?

Comment: @alwaysLearning 'User Access Administrator' is a role for Azure subscription rather than for Azure AD. You can refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell. If you want to grant 'User Access Administrator' to your Azure Automation service principle on Azure subscription. You should use `New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId {object id of your service principle} -RoleDefinitionName "User Access Administrator"`. More samples here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-3.8.0#examples.